# zsh: Complete `command1` the same as `command2 ARG`

Tags: zsh, zsh-completion

Given two commands:

- `command1` - which has completions already set up for it
- `commmand2`- which is a wrapper function, that in the end calls `command1 ARG`

How do I make `command2` complete in the same manner as `command1 ARG1` would *without writing a custom completion for `command1`*?

Here's an example:

```
alias command1="git ls-files"

command2() {
  echo "I'm a wrapper for git ls-files" >&2
  git ls-files $@
}
```

One can do `compdef command2=command1` - but that will make `command2` complete the same way as `git` would and not like `git ls-files`.

**Edit: I'm looking for a broad and general solution that'd also work with commands that do not define separate completion functions such as git has.
For these you can do what Marlon Richert suggested below.**

Here's a better example:

```
alias command1="kubectl get pod"

command2() {
  echo "I'm a wrapper for kubectl get pod" >&2
  kubectl get pod $@
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do this to find out the name of the function that needs to be called:

```bash
% git ls-files ^Xh  # That is, press Ctrl-X, then H.
tags in context :completion::complete:git-ls-files::
    argument-rest options  (_arguments _git-ls-files _git)
tags in context :completion::complete:git-ls-files:argument-rest:
    globbed-files  (_files _arguments _git-ls-files _git)
tags in context :completion::complete:git::
    argument-rest  (_arguments _git)
```

As you can see, it's `_git-ls-files`.

Then, discard the leading `_` and use the remainder as the `$service` argument to `compdef`:

```bash
compdef _git command2=git-ls-files
```

Now it works correctly:

```bash
% command2 ^Xh
tags in context :completion::complete:command2::
    argument-rest options  (_arguments _git-ls-files _git)
tags in context :completion::complete:command2:argument-rest:
    globbed-files  (_files _arguments _git-ls-files _git)
```

---

## Update

For your `kubectl` example, things are slightly less easy, because its completion is *not Zsh-native.* Instead, it's just a thin Zsh wrapper around a *Bash* completion function. In this case, you *will* have to write your own completion function, but thankfully, it's going to be just a mercifully short one:

```
_command2 () {
  # Fake having `kubectl get pod` on the line instead of `command2`.
  local -a words=( kubectl get pod $words[2,-1] )
  local -i CURRENT=$(( CURRENT + 2 ))

  # Restart completion with our new, simulated command line.
  _normal
}
compdef _command2 command2
```

Done!

Comment: Thanks. While this does work for my particular example this isn't quite general enough. This only works if there actually is a completion function defined specifically for the subcommand. Most comps I've seen are not implemented in that way.

Comment: I've updated my post to with a second example ;)

Comment: I saw it. I think I'll mark this question answered even though I explicitly specified:


> without writing a custom completion


but I think there's just isn't a perfectly elegant way to do what I want w/ zsh. I may end up implementing a wrapper function that auto-creates comps in a similar fashion to what you suggested for the kubectl example. Thanks for taking the time to answer, I truly appreciate it.

Comment: Your comment made me realize my second answer can be even shorter. I edited it; have another look. It might help you make a start on that generic wrapper function. :)

Comment: It might be cleaner to replace the `eval` line with `_normal`, which just restarts completion with the new `$words` and `$CURRENT`.